# Android Java App: Extending two classes (walk around)

Tags: java, android, imageview, glsurfaceview

I have two classes, ImageMap, extending ImageView and PageView extending GLSurfaceView, I am using the ImageMap to mainly have hot spots on drawables but I also need to add a page flip/curl animation to it, in order to do that I need those two classes to act as one object, any idea how to do that?

It is totally clear to me that multiple inheritance is not allowed in java.

Comment: not sure but i think you should go with implementing `SurfaceHolder.Callback` directly in to your ImageMap instead of extending GLSurfaceView in PageView.

Comment: you can not extend more than 1 class in java, but you can implement many interfaces

Comment: Java and multiple inheritance is just a no-go. You will have to inherit from one class and implement the methods of the other yourself.
What you can do is implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: Excuse me @Bathsheba, but why on earth did you remove the multiple inheritance tag? It's a question about multiple inheritance, much more than a question about Andoid.

Comment: Java and multiple-inheritance are like chalk and cheese: they don't mix. But I'm not going to lose sleep over it: I believe my edit (which was a result of reviewing a new user edit) increases the likelihood of  the OP attracting answers.

Comment: @Bathsheba multiple inheritance is not the question here, I am totally aware that it is not allowed in Java.

Comment: @pyus13 I could use more help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of really extend two classes. What you can do is:

1. You make a wrapper object, that holds one instance of each object. and simply do `this.ImageMap.filed1` and so. This is more convenient while developing the class. This also allows you to proxy method invocations.
2. You define interfaces which should be implemented, and you make a new class which implements both. This is only for class that use this class to have the interface, without really caring about the implementation.

You may need both things, since the first is about "how to do it" and the second about "how it will be presented to objects that use it".

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not about Android; it's about Java.

Java does not allow for multiple inheritance.

Your reasoning is inaccurate regarding the following:

> in order to do that I need those two classes to act as one object

That's not the case. An 'Activity', for example, does not have to *be* an event handler; it's enough if your 'Activity' can *have* an event handler, e.g. as an inner class which can access the Activity's variables.

Comment: I do know that multiple inheritance is not allowed, both classes are extending other classes to get the job done, both classes are able to show drawables in different ways, I need to show the drawble and have both features of the two classes on one View, bottom line I need the view to have an image map and a page curl effect as well. thanks.

Comment: @AlKafriFiras I got your question wrong, sorry. What you want is to combine the features of two different `View` objects?

Comment: ,it's okay, yes that's exactly what I need.